# Magento 2 Move Top Links to Main Navigation

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to **move the top links** (default message, account links, etc) at the **top to follow the main navigation**.  I have tried:

```
<move element="top.links" destination="page.top" before="-" />
```

and

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links" 
destination="navigation.sections">
<arguments>
<argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
```

among many other variations with no luck.  It places it after the section before the content.  Not after the Nav tag where I want it.  Basically  What is the trick?

Stan